# How to use private property of controller as static property?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, authorize.net

So, the question pretty much explains what i want. Here is the minimum code of what i am doing.

```
class AuthorizeController extends Controller
{
    private $aNetEnvironment;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->aNetEnvironment = env('ANetEnvironment');
    }

    public function setEnvironment()
    {
        $controller = new AnetController\GetCustomerProfileController($request);
        // $this->aNetEnvironment = SANDBOX
        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( 
            \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::$this->aNetEnvironment 
        ); 
    }
}
```

Searching stackoverflow i got two options, have tried both with no luck.

Trying, `{$this->aNetEnvironment}` gives

> syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

Trying, `$$this->aNetEnvironment` gives

> Object of class App\Http\Controllers\AuthorizeController could not be
>   converted to string

**Edit:**

Trying, `${$this->aNetEnvironment}` gives

> Access to undeclared static property:
>   net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::$SANDBOX

Is there any other option ?

Comment: What is the content of `env('ANetEnvironment');`?

Comment: @HCK It's 'SANDBOX'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the PHP's [`constant()` helper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php). From the docs:

> Signature:
>
> ```
> constant ( string $name ) : mixed
> ```
>
> **Return the value of the constant indicated by name.**
>
> `constant()` is useful if you need to retrieve the value of a
>   constant, but do not know its name. I.e. it is stored in a variable or
>   returned by a function.
>
> **This function works also with class constants**.

So in your case:

```
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( 
    constant('\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::' . $this->aNetEnvironment) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use class properties as [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in this way you need to start with a `$` and wrap the property in `{}` e.g. `${$this->property}` so you should be able to use the following in your controller:

```
\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::${$this->aNetEnvironment}
```

Comment: Tried. Gives `Access to undeclared static property: net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::$SANDBOX`

Comment: @shazyriver Ah sorry, I'd assumed that you were trying to access a static property and not a constant since the title of the question says static property. Glad you found the answer though.